# How to make a label in tkinter, at an angle?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tic-tac-toe, diagonal

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe game. When winning, I use the label as a line, but please tell me how to make the label at an angle?

[image: My game]

In this case I need a diagonal line
[image: In this case I need a diagonal line]

I was looking for a solution to this problem, but I didn't find it.

Comment: The shape of `Label` widgets is a fixed rectangle however tkinter Canvas widget has a text object that allows messages to be rotated 360 degrees.

Comment: Another approach might be to colour in the boxes that form the win in green if the player won or red/yellow if the player lost. That way, you probably wont have to deal with `tk.Canvas` but there still will be no diagonal lines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15518276/derek) and [TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard) thank you very much